# Get remote IP of inode using C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, inode

For example my `/proc/net/tcp` contains:

```
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                                         
   2: 0900000A:91E4 0101B85D:0050 01 00000000:00000000 02:00000039 00000000  1000        0 75205 2 0000000000000000 26 4 30 10 -1
```

So `inode = 75205`, communicating with IP `93.184.1.1`.

How can I get this IP (remote address) in C?

I know I can split by space and parse the above manually, but it looks like a bad idea, is there any smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no other way to obtain such information from a user space program. Only the kernel knows that information, and it provides that file exactly to make the information available to user space.

If you [take a look at the source code](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c#L477) of tools like `ss` (aka "socketstat") you'll see that those too query files in `/proc/net/*` to get information about open sockets.

Comment: 1) why in this code it's hard coded `256` as a line size ? is that const for every linux ?  2)each socket can listen and get data from some ip , so what will I see in `/proc/net/tcp` ?  in remote address line?

Comment: @paramikoooo 1) I don't know, ask that to theprogrammers of `ss` 2) what do you mean? each line has the IP encoded in hexadecimal big endian notation, in your example: `0101B85D` -> `93.184.1.1` (0x5D = 93)

Comment: I mean that I can open a client socket (fd X for example) but this socket can get data from number of ip address. what will I see in /proc/net/tcp? Will I see few line with the same Inode?

Comment: @paramikoooo you cannot have multiple IPs connected to the same socket. When you listen for connections, a new socket (and therefore `fd`) is created for every single connection.